# Why is this c# code so slow? Optimisation on directory/file searching & adding needed

Tags: c#, file, directory, treeview

I've written up some fairly quick-ish code and ever since changing it to "SearchOption.AllDirectories", it takes a whole minute to even just load the form/application.

Is there something I can do to make this application run faster on load? Any help/information would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
private const string path = @"R:\Folder One\Folder Two\Folder Three";

public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ListDirectory(treeView1, path);
    treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
    treeView1.SelectedNode.Expand();
}

private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
{
    treeView.Nodes.Clear();
    var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
}

private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        if (!directory.Name.Contains("_") 
             && !directory.Name.Contains("Word Versions") 
             && !directory.Name.Contains("Visio Flowcharts"))
        {
            var dirFileCount = directory.EnumerateFiles(
                         "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
            dirFileCount += directory.EnumerateFiles(
                         "*.xls", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
            dirFileCount += directory.EnumerateFiles(
                         "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
            dirFileCount += directory.EnumerateFiles(
                         "*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
            dirFileCount += directory.EnumerateFiles(
                         "*.docx", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
            dirFileCount += directory.EnumerateFiles(
                         "~*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();

            if (dirFileCount != 0)
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
        }
    }

    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        if (file.Extension.Equals(".pdf") 
           || file.Extension.Equals(".xls") 
           || file.Extension.Equals(".doc") 
           || file.Extension.Equals(".xlsx") 
           || file.Extension.Equals(".docx"))
        {
            if (!file.Name.Contains("~") 
                        || !file.Name.Contains("$"))
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
        }
    }
    return directoryNode;
}
```

Comment: Don't enumerate the same directory many times (`directory.EnumerateFiles`).

Comment: Yes, I did think this but didn't know a way to add more than 1 search string  in the EnumerateFiles parameters.

Comment: Enumerate *all* files(`*.*`) once and get the extensions.

Comment: You are loading all the files/folders in tree view in constructor that too on main ui thread. Rather call the listDirectory function from OnLoad and if you are familiar with Asynchronous programming then list the contents of folder on thread and just the section to add node can be dispatched to main thread. One more thing you can load each sub node once the user expands or clicks on that node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
var dirFileCount = directory.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
dirFileCount += directory.EnumerateFiles("*.xls", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
dirFileCount += directory.EnumerateFiles("*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
dirFileCount += directory.EnumerateFiles("*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
dirFileCount += directory.EnumerateFiles("*.docx", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
dirFileCount += directory.EnumerateFiles("~*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();

if (dirFileCount != 0)
    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
```

is totally **w r o n g**.

Each `EnumerateFiles` will rescan all the subdirectories for a certain type of file. Even worse: you are counting how many files you have in total of that types, but what you want is "is there any file of that extensions"? So after finding the first file `.pdf` you could stop.

You should search for "*" and then filter by the extensions you want, stopping at the first file found.

This

```
var dirFileCount = from p in directory.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                   let extension = p.Extension
                   where extension.Equals("pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                         extension.Equals("xls", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                         extension.Equals("doc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                         extension.Equals("xlsx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                         p.Name.StartsWith("~")
                   select p;

if (dirFileCount.Any())
{
    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
}
```

is probably better.

And are you sure you have to search in subfolders? Because `SearchOption.AllDirectories` will search in subfolders, and not only in the given folder.

Comment: This should be the first step. If you still have performance problems then, you can consider pushing the work to a thread.

Comment: Thank you very much. I realise how silly I Was being now. Loading time has gone down to less than 10 seconds which I'm happy with. Thanks again, I appreciate your time and help.
The only thing I'd change in your code is to include the "." in the extension search string.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just load the root directory on form load, and then load each sub node once the user expands that node.

Further to that, why dont you look at using [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to make the Userinterface more interactive?

> The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a
>   separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads
>   and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem
>   as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you
>   want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated
>   with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient
>   solution.

Answer (score 0):

Run your code in a separate thread

```
Thread yourThread = new System.Threading.Thread(delegate(){
          //Your code 
 });
yourThread.Start();
```

Be care when updating main thread controls, you need to use Invoke , for example in a WPF app

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
                 // your code that update main thread controls
                {}));
```

Answer (score -1):

int doc_filescount = directory_info.GetFileSystemInfos("*.doc").Length;

IT will produce both (".doc" and ".docx") files count in a directory